# grub can't find Xubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu on a partition of a MicroSD card on a laptop running Windows 10 on the internal drive. Attempting to boot to Xubuntu flashes a "Can't find device" error message and sends me to grub (the text interface.)

I've tried to find the correct partition to boot from using ls, but none of them have a /boot directory. I've already run boot-rescue, which didn't seem to do anything useful.

Somehow it seems like grub can't find the Xbuntu installation, but I'm not clear why that's the case. One possibility is that it's some issue with my SD card or the reader; I've heard that sometimes they just refuse to boot. I've been able to boot from USB drives on this machine (that was how I installed Xubuntu and ran boot-repair) but this is my only attempt so far to boot from an SD card.

Comment: Why do you want explicitly SD cards?  BIOS and UEFI don't generally play well with SD cards.

Comment: The internal hard drive is only 30 GiB, so there's barely room for Windows.
I've already been using an SD card to install programs/store most files, and it's easier than a flash drive because it stays flush with the computer: if I put it in a backpack, etc., I don't have to worry about knocking it out.

I might just have to find room on the internal drive, but I'd rather try other thing before doing that.